# Initializing OpenGL without GLUT

Tags: opengl, glut

every introduction and sample that I can find seems to use GLUT or some other framework to "initialize" OpenGL.  Is there a way of initializing OpenGL with just what is available in GL and GLU?  If not, then what is GLUT doing that is not possible without it?

Comment: which is Windows only.

Comment: Yup, but it's still instructive. :-) Thanks!

Comment: "Emphasis on “easy to understand.”" - but I can't read the code for the comments :(

Comment: Nobody mentioned [EGL](http://www.khronos.org/egl)? It's a Khronos standard for interop between operating system and APIs like OpenGL, aimed to unify such things. IDK how wide it's supported today, though.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As luke noted, the code to create and bind the context is specific to each windowing platform.

Here are some functions to get you started in terms of initializing OpenGL on specific platforms:

Windows (a tutorial is [here](http://www.nullterminator.net/opengl32.html))

- wglCreateContext(hDC)

Mac OS X -- OS X has essentially three options: Carbon, Cocoa, and the underlying Core Graphics Layer

- [The entire guide for Mac OS X OpenGL development](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_intro/opengl_intro.html)
- [Carbon](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/AGL_OpenGL/Reference/reference.html): aglCreateContext
- [Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_drawing/opengl_drawing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH404-SW23): Create (or subclass) an NSOpenGLView. They create their own context, and you can read their method documentation to find how to make it current.
- [CoreGraphicsLayer](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGL_OpenGL/Reference/reference.html): CGLCreateContext

Linux

- [glx](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/): glXCreateContext

Comment: Thanks, these are helpful. Now I realize that my problem is specific to the Windows side of the code rather than just OpenGL (i.e. trying to get OpenGL to work on top of - or along side? - GDI+).

Comment: You don't subclass NSOpenGLView, you subclass NSView and use NSOpenGLContext and NSPixelFormat for more flexibility (and you only use an NSOpenGLView for very simple things).

Comment: Also, note that Carbon is pretty much a dead end (no 64 bit support), and CGL can't create a window, so for OS X use NSGL for Cocoa windows, menus etc. and CGL for fullscreen applications.

Comment: The Apple links are now broken. If I can find the new urls I'll suggest an edit.

Comment: Windows link broken too.

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing is initializing a window with an OpenGL context.  This requires some calls to the operating system.  It is not possible to initialize OpenGL with just gl.h and glu.h.  [GLUT](http://www.xmission.com/~nate/glut.html) (or [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/), [SMFL](http://www.sfml-dev.org/), etc) does that work for you in a nice platform independent way.  You can do the initialization with native calls as well.

Answer (score 4):

**[GLX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLX) minimal runnable example**

[image]

Adapted from [here](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/177999-GCC-OpenGL-without-glut?p=1239444&viewfull=1#post1239444).

Also deals with keyboard inputs.

Compile with:

```
gcc glx.c -lGLU -lGL -lX11
```

Tested in Ubuntu 14.04:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#define GLX_GLXEXT_PROTOTYPES
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glx.h>

struct MyWin {
    Display  *display;
    Window win;
    int displayed;
    int width;
    int height;
};

const int WIN_XPOS = 256;
const int WIN_YPOS = 64;
const int WIN_XRES = 320;
const int WIN_YRES = 320;
const int NUM_SAMPLES = 4;

struct MyWin Win;

double elapsedMsec(const struct timeval *start, const struct timeval *stop) {
    return ((stop->tv_sec  - start->tv_sec ) * 1000.0 +
            (stop->tv_usec - start->tv_usec) / 1000.0);
}

void displayCB() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
    glXSwapBuffers(Win.display, Win.win);
}

void keyboardCB(KeySym sym, unsigned char key, int x, int y,
        int *setting_change) {
    switch (tolower(key)) {
        case 27:
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            break;
        case 'k':
            printf("You hit the 'k' key\n");
            break;
        case 0:
            switch (sym) {
                case XK_Left  :
                    printf("You hit the Left Arrow key\n");
                    break;
                case XK_Right :
                    printf("You hit the Right Arrow key\n");
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}

void reshapeCB(int width, int height) {
    Win.width = width;
    Win.height = height;
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 20.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

/* Try to find a framebuffer config that matches
 * the specified pixel requirements.
 */
GLXFBConfig chooseFBConfig(Display *display, int screen) {
    static const int Visual_attribs[] = {
        GLX_X_RENDERABLE  , True,
        GLX_DRAWABLE_TYPE , GLX_WINDOW_BIT,
        GLX_RENDER_TYPE   , GLX_RGBA_BIT,
        GLX_X_VISUAL_TYPE , GLX_TRUE_COLOR,
        GLX_RED_SIZE      , 8,
        GLX_GREEN_SIZE    , 8,
        GLX_BLUE_SIZE     , 8,
        GLX_ALPHA_SIZE    , 8,
        GLX_DEPTH_SIZE    , 24,
        GLX_STENCIL_SIZE  , 8,
        GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER  , True,
        GLX_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, 1,
        GLX_SAMPLES       , 4,
        None
    };
    int attribs [ 100 ] ;
    memcpy(attribs, Visual_attribs, sizeof(Visual_attribs));
    GLXFBConfig ret = 0;
    int fbcount;
    GLXFBConfig *fbc = glXChooseFBConfig(display, screen, attribs, &fbcount);
    if (fbc) {
        if (fbcount >= 1)
            ret = fbc[0];
        XFree(fbc);
    }
    return ret;
}

GLXContext createContext(Display *display, int screen,
        GLXFBConfig fbconfig, XVisualInfo *visinfo, Window window) {
#define GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB       0x2091
#define GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB       0x2092
    typedef GLXContext (*glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc)(Display*,
            GLXFBConfig, GLXContext, int, const int*);
    /* Verify GL driver supports glXCreateContextAttribsARB() */
    /*   Create an old-style GLX context first, to get the correct function ptr. */
    glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc glXCreateContextAttribsARB = 0;
    GLXContext ctx_old = glXCreateContext(display, visinfo, 0, True);
    if (!ctx_old) {
        printf("Could not even allocate an old-style GL context!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    glXMakeCurrent (display, window, ctx_old) ;
    /* Verify that GLX implementation supports the new context create call */
    if (strstr(glXQueryExtensionsString(display, screen),
                "GLX_ARB_create_context") != 0)
        glXCreateContextAttribsARB = (glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc)
            glXGetProcAddress((const GLubyte *) "glXCreateContextAttribsARB");
    if (!glXCreateContextAttribsARB) {
        printf("Can't create new-style GL context\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /* Got the pointer.  Nuke old context. */
    glXMakeCurrent(display, None, 0);
    glXDestroyContext(display, ctx_old);

    /* Try to allocate a GL 4.2 COMPATIBILITY context */
    static int Context_attribs[] = {
        GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 4,
        GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 2,
        GLX_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB , GLX_CONTEXT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
        /*GLX_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB, GLX_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB, */
        /*GLX_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB       , GLX_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB, */
        /*GLX_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB       , GLX_CONTEXT_DEBUG_BIT_ARB, */
        None
    };
    GLXContext context = glXCreateContextAttribsARB(display, fbconfig, 0,
            True, Context_attribs);
    /* Forcably wait on any resulting X errors */
    XSync(display, False);
    if (!context) {
        printf("Failed to allocate a GL 4.2 context\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Created GL 4.2 context\n");
    return context;
}

void createWindow() {
    /* Init X and GLX */
    Win.displayed = 0;
    Display *display = Win.display = XOpenDisplay(":0.0");
    if (!display)
        printf("Cannot open X display\n");
    int    screen   = DefaultScreen(display);
    Window root_win = RootWindow(display, screen);
    if (!glXQueryExtension(display, 0, 0))
        printf("X Server doesn't support GLX extension\n");
    /* Pick an FBconfig and visual */
    GLXFBConfig fbconfig = chooseFBConfig(display, screen);
    if (!fbconfig) {
        printf("Failed to get GLXFBConfig\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    XVisualInfo *visinfo = glXGetVisualFromFBConfig(display, fbconfig);
    if (!visinfo) {
        printf("Failed to get XVisualInfo\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("X Visual ID = 0x%.2x\n", (int)visinfo->visualid);
    /* Create the X window */
    XSetWindowAttributes winAttr ;
    winAttr.event_mask = StructureNotifyMask | KeyPressMask ;
    winAttr.background_pixmap = None ;
    winAttr.background_pixel  = 0    ;
    winAttr.border_pixel      = 0    ;
    winAttr.colormap = XCreateColormap(display, root_win,
            visinfo->visual, AllocNone);
    unsigned int mask = CWBackPixmap | CWBorderPixel | CWColormap | CWEventMask;
    Window win = Win.win = XCreateWindow (display, root_win,
            WIN_XPOS, WIN_YPOS,
            WIN_XRES, WIN_YRES, 0,
            visinfo->depth, InputOutput,
            visinfo->visual, mask, &winAttr) ;
    XStoreName(Win.display, win, "My GLX Window");
    /* Create an OpenGL context and attach it to our X window */
    GLXContext context = createContext(display, screen, fbconfig, visinfo, win);
    if (! glXMakeCurrent(display, win, context))
        printf("glXMakeCurrent failed.\n");
    if (! glXIsDirect (display, glXGetCurrentContext()))
        printf("Indirect GLX rendering context obtained\n");
    /* Display the window */
    XMapWindow(display, win);
    if (! glXMakeCurrent(display, win, context))
        printf("glXMakeCurrent failed.\n");
    printf("Window Size    = %d x %d\n", WIN_XRES, WIN_YRES);
    printf("Window Samples = %d\n", NUM_SAMPLES);
}

void processXEvents(Atom wm_protocols, Atom wm_delete_window) {
    int setting_change = 0;
    while (XEventsQueued(Win.display, QueuedAfterFlush)) {
        XEvent event;
        XNextEvent(Win.display, &event);
        if(event.xany.window != Win.win)
            continue;
        switch (event.type) {
            case MapNotify:
                {
                    Win.displayed = 1;
                    break;
                }
            case ConfigureNotify:
                {
                    XConfigureEvent cevent = event.xconfigure;
                    reshapeCB(cevent.width, cevent.height);
                    break;
                }
            case KeyPress:
                {
                    char chr;
                    KeySym symbol;
                    XComposeStatus status;
                    XLookupString(&event.xkey, &chr, 1, &symbol, &status);
                    keyboardCB(symbol, chr, event.xkey.x, event.xkey.y,
                            &setting_change);
                    break;
                }
            case ClientMessage:
                {
                    if (event.xclient.message_type == wm_protocols &&
                            (Atom)event.xclient.data.l[0] == wm_delete_window) {
                        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                    }
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}

void mainLoop() {
    /* Register to receive window close events (the "X" window manager button) */
    Atom wm_protocols     = XInternAtom(Win.display, "WM_PROTOCOLS"    , False);
    Atom wm_delete_window = XInternAtom(Win.display, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", False);
    XSetWMProtocols(Win.display, Win.win, &wm_delete_window, True);

    while (1) {
        /* Redraw window (after it's mapped) */
        if (Win.displayed)
            displayCB();

        /* Update frame rate */
        struct timeval last_xcheck = {0, 0};
        struct timeval now;
        gettimeofday(&now, 0);

        /* Check X events every 1/10 second */
        if (elapsedMsec(&last_xcheck, &now) > 100) {
            processXEvents(wm_protocols, wm_delete_window);
            last_xcheck = now;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Win.width = WIN_XRES;
    Win.height = WIN_YRES;
    createWindow();

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);

    printf("Valid keys: Left, Right, k, ESC\n");
    printf("Press ESC to quit\n");
    mainLoop();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

TODO failed on Ubuntu 20.04 with:

```
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyCannot open X display
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

and Debian 8 with:

```
Failed to get GLXFBConfig
```

One could always open up the source of [FreeGlut](https://github.com/dcnieho/FreeGLUT) to see how it implements each glut function, but going lower level than GLX is likely hardcore.

**EGL**

Looks like a Khronos standardized alternative to GLX, currently most often used with OpenGL ES.

https://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/demos/tree/src/egl contains examples using Mesa's implementation, but I haven't yet managed to make them work:

```
git checkout mesa-demos-8.1.0
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
```

Fails with:

```
/work/git/mesa-demos/src/egl/opengl/demo1.c:26: undefined reference to `eglGetScreensMESA'
```

But Ubuntu 14.04 has `es2gears` in the `mesa-utils-extra` package, so there must be a way.

See also: [What is EGL And How Can I Use It](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127360/what-is-egl-and-how-can-i-use-it)

Comment: @Ivanzinho and I'm getting `Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyCannot open X display` on Ubuntu 20.04. I'm afraid I don't know how this works well enough to debug it, let me know if you find out!

Comment: @Yunnosch I'm sorry, I didn't read appropriately, I think it was late at night. You are right, the problem I'm specifying is already documented here. Excuse me.

Answer (score 2):

You could grab the [GLUT source code](http://www.xmission.com/~nate/glut.html) and see the init code for whatever platform you are concerned with.

Answer (score -1):

GL is an API, and GLU is an utility library on top of GL. It's completely operating system independent.

OpenGL initialization and extension fetching are platform dependent operations. Therefore you can do about nothing with OpenGL alone.

GLUT is fast insufficient and terribly poor library, and about only it does is that it initializes the opengl context and provides some primitive mouse/keyboard input modules to get you ongoing.

Win32 provides tools to initialize opengl context as well. For linux you could check out GLX. Also, if you want a system independent way of doing it, then you could check out SDL. For different programming languages there may be utilities that provide you a platform independent desktop API.

Answer (score -1):

You may check out the source of Galaxy Forces V2, http://www.galaxy-forces.com/

It implements classes for OpenGL without using GLUT or other libraries on Windows, Mac, and Linux. Using native platform code, all public domain.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a basic and good introduction to how you initialize OpenGL (assuming windows) without using GLUT:

[Init OpenGL without GLUT](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=01)

As Luke said, if you dont want to use GLUT, you need specific information about the operating system you are developing on. Using GLUT will make your code easier to port.

Comment: This sample does use glut?