# What is EGL And How Can I Use It

Tags: linux, opengl, opengl-es, egl

Can Anybody explain me what is EGL and what it does?

How can i use EGL with OpenGL-ES On Linux?

Is EGL a Layer Between Hardware And Operating System?

Answer (score 16):

[EGL](http://www.khronos.org/egl/) is a window system-independent equivalent to the GLX and WGL APIs, which respectively enable OpenGL support in X and Microsoft Windows. It is an interface between Khronos rendering APIs such as OpenGL ES or OpenVG and the underlying native platform window system. It handles graphics context management, surface/buffer binding, and rendering synchronization and enables high-performance, accelerated, mixed-mode 2D and 3D rendering using other Khronos APIs.

[image: EGL Architecture]

There is an implementation for [Mesa](http://www.mesa3d.org/egl.html) called EGL and [covered in the Mesa EGL Wiki](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/gallium/EGLReferenceDrivers/).
Realistically [you can't use](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Xegl) [XEGL / EGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xgl#Xegl),

If you're running on Linux and don't need X then look at [Wayland](http://groups.google.com/group/wayland-display-server) which is a replacement server built on top of MESA.

Comment: well there's also Wayland... that IIRC you CAN use EGL under (and it uses it itself) Mesa DOES have EGL in it, I'm not sure what you can use it for, and I don't think many distros ship mesa with it turned on (IIRC Wayland uses it now, didn't used to) see http://www.mesa3d.org/egl.html, though that might be out of date, also from there it looks like EGL works if your card has a gallium driver

Comment: XEGL has nothing to do with weather or not you can use EGL in your app XEGL is putting the Xorg server on top of EGL, not supporting using EGL under X.

Comment: @spudd86 thanks for the mesa link - I'll add it. I'll clarify my description of XEGL.

Comment: Wayland is a replacement for X11 but it is not a server Wayland is a protocol which is implemented by compositors (sway, mutter, etc.). Client applications can talk to the compositor by using wayland protocol. Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're best reading up definitive references such as [this](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/). I don't see value in paraphrasing that.

There seem to be some Linux implementations referenced in that article. You can't expect folks to give you detailed tutorials here. Instead attempt to use these references and ask specific questions when you get stuck.

Maybe you could view EGL as a kind of dedicated Graphics "OS", personally I see it yet another API, which abstracts graphics.

Comment: EGL is basically a "portable" API that has the same goals as GLX and WGL, provide the stuff needed to create an OpenGL (well really OpenGLES) context (and some related stuff like native pixmaps and things).