# How to create opengl context via drm (Linux)

Tags: linux, opengl, linux-kernel

I want to use OpenGL rendering without X, with google i find it: http://dvdhrm.wordpress.com/2012/08/11/kmscon-linux-kmsdrm-based-virtual-console/ there says that it is possible. I should use DRM and EGL. EGL can create opengl context but requires a NativeWindow. DRM probably will provide me NativeWindow, is not it? Should i use KMS? I know that i must have open source video driver. I want exactly OpenGL context, but not OpenGL ES (Linux). Maybe, someone knows tutorial or example code?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, you need [kms](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man7/drm-kms.7.html) stack ([example](https://github.com/dvdhrm/docs/blob/master/drm-howto/modeset.c)). [Here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/kmscube/-/blob/master/kmscube.c) is a simple example under linux, it use OpenGL es, But the step to have it working against OpenGL api are simple.

In the egl attribs set `EGL_RENRERABLE_TYPE` to `EGL_OPENGL_BIT`

And tell egl which api to bind to:

```
eglBindAPI(EGL_OPENGL_API);
```

Be sure to have latest kernel drivers and `mesa-dev`, `libdrm-dev`, `libgbm-dev`. This pieces of code is portable on android, it's just not so easy to have default android graphic stack silenced.

*note: I had trouble with 32bit version, but still don't know why. those libs are actively developed, so not sure it wasn't a bug.*

*note2: depending on your GLSL version, float precision is supported or not.

```
precision mediump float;
```

note3: if you have permision failure with `/dev/dri/card0`, grant it with:

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/dri/card0
```

or add current user to `video` group with

```
sudo adduser $user video
```

you may also setguid for your executable with group set to video. (maybe best option)

Comment: Hi, j-p! I'am searching for the similar example, but for android devices. As i understand there is no DRM stack in android. I guess lowlevel graphic api must work through fb0 and /dev/ion devices, but i have no example. Please, refer my question if you have any notes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742552/framebuffer-egl-example-segfault

Comment: There is libdrm for android, (libdrm1.so) on mine, but I don't remember if I compile one myself or if it's native

Comment: how would I do this across multiple processes? Ie. How does a compositor work? how can I have multiple processed with their own EGL contexts and composite them from the master process?

Comment: https://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/sdk/docs/man/html/eglMakeCurrent.xhtml

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late to the party, but you might want to give [SRM (Simple Rendering Manager)](https://github.com/CuarzoSoftware/SRM) a shot. It's a C library that abstracts away all the DRM/KMS complexities, so you can focus on the OpenGL ES 2.0 part of your application. Here's a basic example that simply changes the color of all connected displays with glClear():

```
#include <SRMCore.h>
#include <SRMDevice.h>
#include <SRMListener.h>
#include <SRMConnector.h>
#include <SRMConnectorMode.h>
#include <SRMBuffer.h>

#include <SRMList.h>
#include <SRMLog.h>

#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2ext.h>

#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float color = 0.f;

/* Opens a DRM device */
static int openRestricted(const char *path, int flags, void *userData)
{
    SRM_UNUSED(userData);

    // Here something like libseat could be used instead
    return open(path, flags);
}

/* Closes a DRM device */
static void closeRestricted(int fd, void *userData)
{
    SRM_UNUSED(userData);
    close(fd);
}

static SRMInterface srmInterface =
{
    .openRestricted = &openRestricted,
    .closeRestricted = &closeRestricted
};

static void initializeGL(SRMConnector *connector, void *userData)
{
    SRM_UNUSED(userData);

    /* You must not do any drawing here as it won't make it to
     * the screen. */

    SRMConnectorMode *mode = srmConnectorGetCurrentMode(connector);

    glViewport(0, 
               0, 
               srmConnectorModeGetWidth(mode), 
               srmConnectorModeGetHeight(mode));

    // Schedule a repaint (this eventually calls paintGL() later, not directly)
    srmConnectorRepaint(connector);
}

static void paintGL(SRMConnector *connector, void *userData)
{
    SRM_UNUSED(userData);

    glClearColor((sinf(color) + 1.f) / 2.f,
                 (sinf(color * 0.5f) + 1.f) / 2.f,
                 (sinf(color * 0.25f) + 1.f) / 2.f,
                 1.f);

    color += 0.01f;

    if (color > M_PI*4.f)
        color = 0.f;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    srmConnectorRepaint(connector);
}

static void resizeGL(SRMConnector *connector, void *userData)
{
    /* You must not do any drawing here as it won't make it to
     * the screen.
     * This is called when the connector changes its current mode,
     * set with srmConnectorSetMode() */

    // Reuse initializeGL() as it only sets the viewport
    initializeGL(connector, userData);
}

static void pageFlipped(SRMConnector *connector, void *userData)
{
    SRM_UNUSED(connector);
    SRM_UNUSED(userData);

    /* You must not do any drawing here as it won't make it to
     * the screen.
     * This is called when the last rendered frame is now being
     * displayed on screen.
     * Google v-sync for more info. */
}

static void uninitializeGL(SRMConnector *connector, void *userData)
{
    SRM_UNUSED(connector);
    SRM_UNUSED(userData);

    /* You must not do any drawing here as it won't make it to
     * the screen.
     * Here you should free any resource created on initializeGL()
     * like shaders, programs, textures, etc. */
}

static SRMConnectorInterface connectorInterface =
{
    .initializeGL = &initializeGL,
    .paintGL = &paintGL,
    .resizeGL = &resizeGL,
    .pageFlipped = &pageFlipped,
    .uninitializeGL = &uninitializeGL
};

static void connectorPluggedEventHandler(SRMListener *listener, SRMConnector *connector)
{
    SRM_UNUSED(listener);

    /* This is called when a new connector is avaliable (E.g. Plugging an HDMI display). */

    /* Got a new connector, let's render on it */
    if (!srmConnectorInitialize(connector, &connectorInterface, NULL))
        SRMError("[srm-basic] Failed to initialize connector %s.",
                 srmConnectorGetModel(connector));
}

static void connectorUnpluggedEventHandler(SRMListener *listener, SRMConnector *connector)
{
    SRM_UNUSED(listener);
    SRM_UNUSED(connector);

    /* This is called when a connector is no longer avaliable (E.g. Unplugging an HDMI display). */

    /* The connnector is automatically uninitialized after this event (if initialized)
     * so calling srmConnectorUninitialize() is a no-op. */
}

int main(void)
{
    setenv("SRM_DEBUG", "4", 1);
    setenv("SRM_EGL_DEBUG", "4", 1);

    SRMCore *core = srmCoreCreate(&srmInterface, NULL);

    if (!core)
    {
        SRMFatal("[srm-basic] Failed to initialize SRM core.");
        return 1;
    }

    // Subscribe to Udev events
    SRMListener *connectorPluggedEventListener = srmCoreAddConnectorPluggedEventListener(core, &connectorPluggedEventHandler, NULL);
    SRMListener *connectorUnpluggedEventListener = srmCoreAddConnectorUnpluggedEventListener(core, &connectorUnpluggedEventHandler, NULL);

    // Find and initialize avaliable connectors

    // Loop each GPU (device)
    SRMListForeach (deviceIt, srmCoreGetDevices(core))
    {
        SRMDevice *device = srmListItemGetData(deviceIt);

        // Loop each GPU connector (screen)
        SRMListForeach (connectorIt, srmDeviceGetConnectors(device))
        {
            SRMConnector *connector = srmListItemGetData(connectorIt);

            if (srmConnectorIsConnected(connector))
            {
                if (!srmConnectorInitialize(connector, &connectorInterface, NULL))
                    SRMError("[srm-basic] Failed to initialize connector %s.",
                             srmConnectorGetModel(connector));
            }
        }
    }

    while (1)
    {
        /* Udev monitor poll DRM devices/connectors hotplugging events (-1 disables timeout).
         * To get a pollable FD use srmCoreGetMonitorFD() */

        if (srmCoreProccessMonitor(core, -1) < 0)
            break;
    }

    /* Unsubscribe to DRM events
     *
     * These listeners are automatically destroyed when calling srmCoreDestroy()
     * so there is no need to free them manually.
     * This is here just to show how to unsubscribe to events on the fly. */

    srmListenerDestroy(connectorPluggedEventListener);
    srmListenerDestroy(connectorUnpluggedEventListener);

    // Finish SRM
    srmCoreDestroy(core);

    return 0;
}
```

Additionally, it offers several other features, including the handy ability for automatic texture sharing across GPUs from a single allocation.