# OpenGL ES2 direct output to display buffer on Linux platform

Tags: c++, opengl-es, raspberry-pi, x11

I have been able to compile and run examples from [http://opengles-book-samples.googlecode.com/](http://opengles-book-samples.googlecode.com)

using Raspberry Pi, BeagleBone, and Hummingboard in Gnome without issues.

Then, for the Raspberry Pi, I was able to run the same examples without the windowing system (directly from shell) using the examples from the following link

[enter link description here](https://benosteen.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/using-opengl-es-2-0-on-the-raspberry-pi-without-x-windows/)

However, the same examples did not work on the other boards, this is because of the Bcm_host library, which is only available on the Pi.

The same examples did work however, when I compiled without the RPI_NO_X cflag. 
But they required to be executed from Gnome and they ran very slow, about 30x slower on a board that's faster than the Pi. They would not run without X11

My question is, is X11 necessary for OpenGL? Shouldn't it be possible to have OpenGL output directly to the video/display/frame buffer?

Can anyone help point in the right direction to get started

Comment: Your problem isn't with X itself; by itself it shouldn't add so much difference. More likely you're missing GPU drivers, hence poor performance. But if you really want to - yes, you can build mesa to output to fbdev rather than X. Take a look at https://blog.visucore.com/2013/2/25/building-mesa-without-x11

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139886/how-to-create-opengl-context-via-drm-linux

Comment: Did you get this working with the Hummingboard please?  If so, please would you consider posting a brief overview of the steps you took to do this?