# Is there a built-in OpenGL GUI windowing library in XCode 6 (OS X 10.10)?

Tags: c++, opengl, xcode6, osx-yosemite

I am trying to develop a **C++** application that uses OpenGL. I set up everything in XCode 6.4 (running on OS X 10.10.5) and I was able to get the OpenGL framework working. However, I can't figure out how to draw the graphics to a GUI window.

I know that GLUT is available, but it is deprecated and I'd rather avoid using it. Instead, is there a way of using some of Apple's native windowing systems (I assume there should be something available in the Cocoa API)?

I would rather avoid downloading additional libraries like SDL or Qt since I do not have root access on this machine and maintaining third-party libraries those may be challenging.

Comment: On the contrary, it's advised that you do use SDL, GLFW or Qt. For what it's worth, you don't have to be root in order to install those libraries; you simply download them, extract, and include the headers/link the shared libraries to your application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initializing OpenGL without GLUT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879035/initializing-opengl-without-glut)